# delete marker from map and database

Tags: html, database, maps, marker

I am making a web in html that shows a google map with some markers loaded from a database and some infor when I right click it. I want to be able to left click on it a get a "delete" button in a info window, but also want to delete the marker from the database. Any help is very much apreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [Google Maps API for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).
API provides methods for listening to marker click ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)) and Info windows ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)) which may be helpful in building complete solution.

For deleting markers from database you should setup API endpoint which may be called by browser [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) with marker ID as param.

Comment: I am using  the  methods for listening to marker click and Info windows and that part is working fine. I didn't know about the lasta part. Checking it right now.